# how to select a select box which is not having any class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select a select box which is not having any class name

```
  Minute : <select name="dob_minute'+$i+'[]" class="" style="width: 56px">
  <option value="">--------</option></select>
```

I can not select it by using name. I am having some other issues in it. That is the reason that I am not selecting by name

Comment: there are many was to select elements with JQuery. Provide more detail so we can determine what is unique about this specific one

Comment: @musefan You are absolutely correct!

Comment: @Mansoor Why don't you go through the documentation or just do some work on google you can find loads of information about this little issue you are facing. Plz do some googling.

Comment: I can not select it by using name. I am having some other issues in it. That is the reason that I am not selecting by name

Answer (score 1):

This will select any select element that has a name attribute that begins with 'dob_minute' so it doesn't matter what variables are added after that.

```
$('select[name^="dob_minute"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *attribute selector*:

```
$('select[class=""]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the select using [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like below,

For a select like below,

```
<select name="mySelect">
   <option>...</option>
</select>
```

You can find the select using attribute equals selector below,

```
$('select[name="mySelect"]').val();
```

Comment: I can not select it by using name. I am having some other issues in it. That is the reason that I am not selecting by name

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = document.getElementsByName("dob_minute'+$i+'[]")[0];
```

Comment: I can not select it by using name. I am having some other issues in it. That is the reason that I am not selecting by name

Answer (score 0):

Use the select like this

```
$('select[name=dob_minute]').val()
```